# conda won't install newest version snakemake

Tags: conda, snakemake

I want to use the newest version of snakemake in order to be able to use the github wrappers instead of the old bitbucket wrappers. But if I do `conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda snakemake` it  installs snakemake 5.3.0. Even though bioconda seems to be at 5.11.2. Any idea?

Comment: Most likely, the newer version would create a conflict with other packages. Have you tried to install in a fresh environment?

Comment: More generally, Snakemake currently has some issues with its `datrie` dependency, which is described [here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/246). This is fixed for Python3.7 but not 3.8. Be aware, therefore, that Snakemake is not compatible with Python3.8 at present.